# GitLab mantains old state on branch after git reset

Tags: git, vuejs2, gitlab, pycharm, webstorm

My git state was messy and disorganized with some commits and merges, so I did proper backups and on WebStorm used "Reset branch to here", then I force pushed the changes. The GitLab history page shows everything as correct, perfect and working, but when I try to access the website associated with the project, it maintains the state before the changes. I got the same bugs and problems that I had before the reset, fields that should not be there, and even commits that I send there seem not to be effective.

I even tried to change a button link and it maintains the old link despite the code having the new URL.

I am not sure how to move on with this. I use Vue and I did build the files correctly before committing again, adding versioned and unversioned files. Any suggestions on how to make things work properly?

Thank you!

I tried building the project, adding and dropping commits. Before using git push, I unprotected the branch.

Edit: Clearing the cache or changing browser do not work.

Comment: The round loading bar that normally shows on GitLab when I push a commit does not appear anymore. It is as if GitLab did not recognize changed, despite listing them on the git history.